# Log4j Bridge library using java 7

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

Can anyone help to understand which slf4j and log4j bridge libraries (along with version) have to use for Java 7 version when migrating from log4j1.x to log4j2.x

Comment: I believe you don't want to change to log4j2 hence you want to use bridge. Let me know if that is the correct understanding. If not then you don't need bridge library.

Answer (score 0):

SLF4J comes up with a module called log4j-over-slf4j. It allows log4j users to migrate existing applications to SLF4J without changing a single line of code but simply by replacing the log4j.jar file with log4j-over-slf4j.jar.

**How does it work?**
The log4j-over-slf4j module contains replacements of most widely used log4j classes, namely org.apache.log4j.Category, org.apache.log4j.Logger, org.apache.log4j.Priority, org.apache.log4j.Level, org.apache.log4j.MDC, and org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator. These replacement classes redirect all work to their corresponding SLF4J classes.

To use log4j-over-slf4j in your own application, the first step is to locate and then to replace log4j.jar with log4j-over-slf4j.jar. Note that you still need an SLF4J binding and its dependencies for log4j-over-slf4j to work properly.

In most situations, replacing a jar file is all it takes in order to migrate from log4j to SLF4J.

**To use slf4j along with log4j 1.2, you will require:**

log4j-over-slf4j (1.7.36)
slf4j-api (1.7.36)
log4j-api (2.18.0)
log4j-core (2.18.0)
log4j-slf4j-impl (2.18.0)